# SailsJS uniqueness scope multiple columns

Tags: sails.js

For single uniqueness check:

```
title: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    }

dateTime: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    }
```

Is there a way to limit model creation/update based on uniqueness spanning more than 1 column? Let's say now I need the table to be unique by using string + dateTime. Something like `validates :title, uniqueness: { scope: :dateTime, :case_sensitive => false } in Rails.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`afterValidate`](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html) to add your own validation spanning across more than one columns.

```
afterValidate: function (values, cb) {
    Foo.findOne({
        title: values.title,
        dateTime: values.dateTime
    }).exec(function(err, foo){
        if(err) return cb(err);
        if(foo) return cb('Not unique');
        cb(null, values);
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I did, but I thought there should be a better way. I guess I'll just settle for this. I just wished I didn't had to do so many unnecessary queries. You seem to have replied to quite a lot of my questions. Are you a contributor to sails?

Comment: Not nearly :) I've been using sails for about a year now so I'm pretty familiar with a bunch of concepts. I got a bunch of help here so I was just giving back. Also the [issues](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues) are in a really good shape if you want someone to have a look at a particularly nasty problem.

Comment: I'd rather not raise issues if I could not contribute to the repo. Actually I know how this whole thing works. There can be hacks to making it work, but coming from Rails, I felt that many common problems are still not addressed in sails. But the last time I checked it had over 10k stars. Seems like one of the more popular nodejs frameworks out there.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer to this problem when I found this trick could work.

For this Model

```
title: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
} 
dateTime: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
}
```

We can use

```
Model.findOrCreate({title:"Your Title",dateTime:"DateTime"}).exec(console.log)
```

Here unique=true is removed from the two attributes. Here are the effects of using unique=true as originally asked in the question.

a) When not using unique=true

```
Data 1: title="Google", dateTime="2015-05-25T10:26:20.428Z" | will get accepeted
Data 2: title="Facebook", dateTime="2015-05-25T10:26:20.428Z" | will get accepeted
Data 3: title="Google", dateTime="2015-05-25T10:26:20.428Z" | will get rejected (because same as 1)
```

b) When using unique=true

```
Data 1: title="Google", dateTime="2015-05-25T10:26:20.428Z" | will get accepeted
Data 2: title="Facebook", dateTime="2015-05-25T10:26:20.428Z" | will get rejected (because dateTime is same as 1)
Data 3: title="Facebook", dateTime="2016-06-26T10:26:20.428Z" | will get rejected (because title is same as 2)
```